# SSIS export view to text file with fixed spacing

Tags: sql, ssis, export, text-files, newline

I would like to export data from a view to a text file. I am using a package to do this. 
The package can run and gives as an output a textfile indeed.
The format is based on fixed width spacing. However each record-line should end with an CRLF. In order for the next record to start on a new line.

How can this be best accomplished?

thanks for your help,
best regards,
Mano

Comment: Have you tried with Format option - Ragged right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Murthy said you can accomplish that with Ragged Right:

[image]

[image]

[image]